# Continuous servo "misbehaving' with arduino uno

Tags: arduino, serial, servo

I've recently got a TowerPro MG996R 360 degrees Robotic servo and after many tries I still can't get it to work properly. Using the Arduino's Servo library I wrote a simple program that writes a value to a servo and displays it through serial:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo test;

void setup() {
  test.attach(9);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  test.write(90);
}


int input;

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    input = Serial.parseInt();
    test.write(input);
    Serial.print(test.read());
    Serial.print("\n");
  }
}
```

So the two problems that occured to me are:

1. When I input something servo runs for about a second and then stops. In the serial monitor the value read from servo just resets to 0.
2. The way servo reacts to the value written to it is all over the place. Above 100 it works fine, but whenever I type something below that it acts weird. For values between 80 to 50 it just turns for about one degree and stops. For values below that it turns at full speed.

I have no idea what could cause these issues. The servo is powered separately by a 5V 3A power supply (I have also connected the supply's ground with arduino's ground pin). Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The best way of learning to use Arduino and program with its libraries is start with a known-to-work sketch. If you search in Google, you will find a [link for the Arduino web site]  (https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/Kub_Luk/using-serial-monitor-to-control-servo-motor-cc1daf) where there is a complete sketch for controlling servo position from serial terminal. I suggest that you start with that script, understand how it works, the function of each line, and progressively reduce the commands untill you reach the desired funcionality.

Comment: That sounds about like how a continuous rotation servo *should* behave.  There might be some offset error (very hard to avoid) but what did you expect it to do differently?

Comment: Well I thought that it is supposed to keep going after I input some number using .write() function. Also I can't control the speed of the servo properly. When it rotates in one direction it's fine but in the other it either doesn't move at all or spins at full speed.